# What effect does a Category have on a class implementing a protocol?

Tags: objective-c

For my current project, I have some protocol and I declare a category on a class implementing this protocol:

```
@interface MyClass (ImplementingMyProtocol) <MyProtocol>

@end


@implementation

// Implementation of protocol

@end
```

I think there are two possibilities how this scheme could be interpreted:

1. The category only applies to `MyClass` subclasses conforming to `MyProtocol`.
2. The category applies to all instances of `MyClass` with the effect of implementing `MyProtocol` by category.

Which of these two possibilities actually applies? I don't know how the compiler interprets this declaration and I didn't find any help or documentation on that topic. I think I know how to deal with both of these two options, nevertheless to do so I need to know which one actually is the way the compiler interprets my code.

Answer (score 1):

the effect of the above will be, that it is made known to xcode that the Class MyClass DOES intend to implement the given protocol MyProtocol
it will also conform to it at runtime

---

the protocol is only 'metainfo' -- it is nothing the runtime needs .. the runtime only knows hey I have this class and hey I should call This method on it

it doesnt check conformance to some protocol

---

**protocols are only there for type checking** by the IDE (which can give you warnings) and you can ask a class at runtime but objC doesnt

---

**so they arent needed for execution at all** :D

Comment: But what about the "conformsToProtocol"-Method? Isn't this some protocol related information the runtime knows about? I can see your point that with Objective C I can send any kind of message to any object and hope for a reply, but I thought that protocols can be used at runtime (with the method mentioned above) to perform some additional checking on objects whether or whether not it could give me an error sending some message to an object ...

Comment: yes .... "and you can ask a class at runtime but objC doesnt" -- the runtime doesnt care

Comment: the check will be YES for the example given